# Decide which component to have focus on launch?

Tags: java, swing

Im working on a small java program and have a small login window when the application launches. I have a problem with Swing giving focus to the top field in the window because i have a focus listener on the field to be able to set/remove a default text in the textField. So my question is, how can i tell swing not to give focus to the field on launch?

```
    private JTextField createLoginField() {

    final JTextField nameField = new JTextField();

    nameField.setFont(new Font("Ubuntu Mono", Font.ITALIC, 16));
    nameField.setToolTipText("Email or username");
    nameField.setText("Username or email");

    nameField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

            nameField.setText("");
            nameField.setFont(new Font("Ubuntu Mono", Font.PLAIN, 16));

        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

            nameField.setFont(new Font("Ubuntu Mono", Font.ITALIC, 16));
            nameField.setText("Username or email");

        }
    });

    return nameField;

}
```

Comment: So you basically want to give it a focus effect, but not want it to be the first object that is focused on launch?

Comment: `nameField.setFont(new Font("Ubuntu Mono", Font.ITALIC, 16));`  Well that's very 'not cross-platform' (unless the font is distributed with the app.)!

Answer (score 0):

> i have a focus listener on the field to be able to set/remove a default text in the textField.

Don't use the FocusListener.

Instead you can use the [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) class which you configure to only remove the prompt once the user actually types text into the text field.

Or you can use:

```
component.requestFocusInWindow();
```

to have another component request focus. However this method can only be invoked on a visible component on a visible GUI. So the code would be:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
component.requestFocusInWindow();
```